# Anim8or to Cinema 4D

Tags: windows, animation, 3d, cinema-4d

Is it possible to convert Anim8or to Cinema 4D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just export to .obj and i can import that into Cinema 4D.